# C: difference from a code with a printf to another who hasn't

Tags: c, printf

Hi i'm new in the world of C and there is something really odd about my code. The objective is to create a function that can trim a string with spaces and/or tabs at the beginnig and at the end. I cannot use String lib.

The problem is that there is a printf  in my code just for testing and it does the job very well. But if i delete that printf the function doesn't work properly... Anyone can help me please?

Here's the code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

short trim(short idx,char*str,short dir){   //gives the index to trim
    while(*(str+idx)==' ' || *(str+idx)=='\t')
        idx+=dir;
    return idx;
}

short findEnd(char *str){   // find the end of the string
    int ret=0;
    while(*(str+ret)!='\0')ret++;
    return ret-1;
}

char *strtrim(char *str){   //The function that trims the string
    short begin=trim(0,str,1);
    short end=trim(findEnd(str),str,-1)+1;
    char ret[end-begin];
    for (short i=begin; (i-begin)<sizeof(ret);i++){
        ret[i-begin]=*(str+i);
        printf("%d\n",i);// <--------------------------------this is the printf
    }
    char *c=&ret[0];
    return c;
}

int len(char *str){// return the length of the given string
    int ret=0;
    for(int i=0;*(str+i)!='\0';i++){
        printf("%d %c\n",i,*(str+i));// another printf for testing porpuses
        ret=i;
    }
    return ret;
}


int main(){
    char *str="     this is a great test to test your testing skills        ";
    printf("%d\n",len(strtrim(str)));
}
```

How can just a printf makes such a difference? If i use printf everytime i run it gives me the same and the correct output, however if i don't use the printf it gives me a totally different output eveytime i run it and it's always the wrong one

Comment: `strtrim` returns a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: Retired Ninja thank you for your reply. Yes strtrim return a pointer (sorry for that mistake). However my question has nothing to do with local variable memory (i think) it's about printf that makes a total diference. with printf eveything is fine everytime i run it but without that single printf everything goes wrong

Comment: Once you have undefined behavior, seemingly irrelevant changes can have unpredictable effects. Fix the UB, *then* worry about whether your corrected code behaves properly.

Comment: The printf makes the stack different perhaps making your array allocate differently.  It's still wrong, but seems to work.  The worst bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `strtrim`, you use `char ret[end-begin];` to assign to the return pointer value.

This is local memory, and hasn't the proper lifespan: it's made available to other parts of the program as soon as you exit the routine: undefined behaviour.

"it works when I insert/remove a `printf`" should be a red flag for this kind of mistake.

You can fix it like:

- using `strdup` to return an actually allocated *copy* of your result
- pass another parameter to be filled by the routine

Since you cannot change function prototype, just allocate inside the function. If you cannot use `strdup` or any copy function, you can still do it.

replace that code:

```
char ret[end-begin];
```

by the following:

```
char *ret = malloc(end-begin);
```

then return `ret` instead of `c`.

you have an allocated string now, don't forget to `free` it in the caller when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. Unfortenally i cannot change the parameters and i cannot use another libraries like String...
Is there any other way to keep the data in the memory?

Comment: oh yeah... sorry it's my first post xD